# How can I track down this memory related bug in my C++ program when VSC gives no indication of the error?

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger

I have written a C++ program which has expanded to ~80 files and multiple classes. Most times I after I have made a change and recompiled, VSC will pause execution when either allocating or deallocating memory. For example, it will pause execution in the library file new_allocator.h on the line:

```
return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
```

In the Call Stack window, thread 1 is "PAUSED ON PAUSE". If I click on the Run icon, execution continues and the program completes correctly. If instead I run the program from the command line, it quits at the point where VSC pauses.

I can see the stack trace and can see that the last line in my code is:

```
s_ptr->section_details()->push_back(*sd_ptr);
```

I can see that sd_ptr does point at a valid structure, as does s_ptr.

I am stumped on what to look at the determine what the problem actually is. If I change the code, the problem may move to a different point in my code.

Why isn't VSC more specific about the issue? How can I find out what the issue actually is?

Comment: `->push_back` is suspicious... Do you allocate `std::vector`?

Comment: Do you respect [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) ?

Comment: Even the best debugger in the world is not going to put up a giant arrow with a sign underneath it "here's where your bug is". C++ is too complicated for that. Just because the program crashes on one particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere in the code that executed up until that point, but memory corruption/wild pointer dereference didn't cause an immediate crash, and the program simply limped a long for a little bit more until things finally come to a screeching halt.

Comment: It's impossible to tell by inspection that a structure is valid, only that it definitely isn't. That it looks good is only very weak evidence for validity.

Comment: The structure being copied (pointed to by sd_ptr) contains 2 numbers and a vector<char>. I don't "new" anything so I don't see why there would be any issue creating/copying it, although I haven't written an explicit copy operator.

Comment: running with sanitization enabled would be very helpful, but I am not sure if vscode supports it, I know Visual Studio does. Maybe you can compile your code with clang?

Comment: If you can compile it on WSL, then Valgrind may be a good tool. Actually, it can show memory violations on the source code level. https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html.

Comment: You might be exceeding available native memory so it's shifting low usage ram into disk cache.